# python string split resulting in list with wrong indexes

Tags: python, string, list, pycharm

```
file = open(fullname, 'r')
        for line in file:
                if line.endswith('\n'): line = line[:-1]
                line = line.split(',')
                for tile in line:
                        index = line.index(tile)
                        tile = tile.split('>')
                        print(tile)
                        copies = int(tile[1])
                        tile = tile * copies
                        line[index:index+1] = tile
```

the text file format:
`block>20, otherblock>10`

the output:

```
['block', '20']
['20']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CAIO/Documents/Pycharm/vitoria/main.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/CAIO/Documents/Pycharm/vitoria/main.py", line 77, in main
    test_map = MapClass("map.txt")
  File "C:/Users/CAIO/Documents/Pycharm/vitoria/main.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.load_map(name)
  File "C:/Users/CAIO/Documents/Pycharm/vitoria/main.py", line 39, in load_map
    copies = int(tile[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

when i reference tile[1] it states the index is invalid, and when i reference tile[0] it's just 'block', not ['block','10'].
printing tile before spliting results in :

```
'block>20'
'20'
```

i'm too tired for this at this point, it's probably something dumb i'm skipping

Comment: Please make your question more elaborate

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: If you begin by using different variable names before and after `split` and the multiplication by `copies`; you can see more easily what you’re doing.

Comment: issue is with line `line[index:index+1] = tile`
you are iterating all the element in the list and when you reach for the last element in the list and try `index+1` will always give index out of bound error as current index is last and there is no element at `index+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like you want to expand the 'text>count' format with the text repeated 'count' times.

Try this code. Note that this code removes the leading space before the text.

```
ss = '''
block>20, otherblock>10
b2>21, ob2>12
b3>22, ob3>13
'''.strip()

with open('test.csv','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write test file


##############
  
fullname = 'test.csv'

alllines = []

file = open(fullname, 'r')
for line in file:
    lineout = line
    if line.endswith('\n'): line = line[:-1]
    line = line.split(',')
    for idx,tile in enumerate(line):
        #index = line.index(tile)        
        tilex = tile.strip().split('>')
        copies = int(tilex[1])
        tilex2 = tilex[0] * copies
        lineout = lineout.replace(tile, tilex2)
    alllines.append(lineout)
print(''.join(alllines))
```

Output

```
blockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblockblock,otherblockotherblockotherblockotherblockotherblockotherblockotherblockotherblockotherblockotherblock
b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2,ob2ob2ob2ob2ob2ob2ob2ob2ob2ob2ob2ob2
b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3,ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3ob3
```

If you want minimal code, you can use list comprehension.

```
ss = '''
block>20, otherblock>10
b2>21, ob2>12
b3>22, ob3>13
'''.strip()

with open('test.csv','w') as f: f.write(ss)   # write test file

#######################

with open(fullname, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    xx = '\n'.join([','.join([e.split('>')[0]*int(e.split('>')[1]) for e in ln.split(', ')]) for ln in lines])
    print(xx)
```

Output is the same